# R test categorical column

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to create test set using `createDataPartition` in caret (or other method) which I can do based on label column in my data set. 
But my additional requirement is that my data has one categorical column (say: ID with values as ID1, ID2....ID10 for examples in data set) I want that all the observations with particular ID should be either in train set or in test set. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution doesn't use caret, but I think it does what you want. 
Using dplyr to group your `data.frame` based on `ID` and then randomly assign each group a 0/1 label. You can then subset based on that.

```
#very small sample data set
dat <- data.frame(id=sample(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), size = 25, replace =T), 
                  val1=rnorm(25), val2=rnorm(25) )

dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(label = rbinom(1, 1, 0.7) )

train <- subset(dat2, label==1)
test  <- subset(dat2, label==0)
```